# How can I hide the Tool-bar in Emacs persistently?

Tags: linux, emacs, toolbar

I have installed emacs23 on Linux Mint 8. I would like to hide the toolbar, and I can do it with `Options > Show/Hide > Tool-bar`. But the Tool-bar comes back next time I start emacs. How can I hide it persistently?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add the following to your init file (`~/.emacs` or `_emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`):

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)
```

Comment: Could `false` be used instead of `-1` as the value to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Leif I don't know about `false`. But you *can* do `0`, which is what I use, and that's pretty well understood to be false-y.

Answer (score 11):

Emacs has a nice built-in customization interface.

Select `Options › Customize Emacs › Specific Option`, start typing `tool`, then hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see the options starting with `tool`. Choose `tool-bar-mode` then. Toggle its value to switch it off, and press `Save for future sessions`.

Comment: Thanks, this was a more general solution. But when I pressed "Save for future sessions", I got "Cannot save customixations; init file was not fully loaded" ...so I think I have some problem with my `.emacs`-file, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Sanoj: the best fix for that, if you don't know any lisp, is to make an empty .emacs, and then copy parts of your old .emacs in one at a time and make sure no errors show up in the *Messages* buffer at startup for each portion you add back in. Or you can put a ";" before lines to comment them out, and follow a similar process of uncommenting a small section, and making sure there are no errors when you restart.

Answer (score 7):

Just for future reference.

*~/.emacs* file with tool-bar, menu-bar and scroll-bar hidden

```
;; Disabling things
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
(menu-bar-mode -1) 
(toggle-scroll-bar -1) 
(tool-bar-mode -1) 

;;Note: If, after turning any of these off, you want to re-enable them for a single emacs window, you can do so by pressing Meta-x and then typing the command at the M-x prompt. (Copied from Web)
;;Example:
;;M-x tool-bar-mode
;;will turn the toolbar back on. 
;;-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, your emacs will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9reDf.png).

Answer (score 6):

I agree with michael. But if you only add this line to your .emacs file, there will be errors when you run emacs in the command line mode. Thus, a better solution may be adding the following to you .emacs file:

```
(if window-system
    (tool-bar-mode -1)
)
```

so that, tool bar will be hidden only when you run it in GUI. Emacs in command line mode does not seem to have a tool bar.

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem with Emacs 24 FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread but none of the answers helped me directly. I wanted to hide the tab bar rightaway but I wanted to also be able to show it if needed.

So after some searching and then RTF[M](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Bars.html) I realized that one can do `M-x toggle-frame-tab-bar`. This is handy as you can bind it to a key and toggle it whenever you want it in that particular frame. In Emacs 28.2 it seems like there is a bug and the frame is not refreshed/repainted after the toggle, but when you move the point (e.g `C-n`) then you see the effect of the toggle.