# How can I apply a color-scheme (.el file) in emacs?

Tags: emacs, colors, elisp

I have downloaded [zenburn.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/zenburn.el) that is a color-scheme for Emacs, but I don´t know how I can apply it to emacs. I am a beginner in emacs.

How do I apply my .el file to emacs? Can I do some linking from my `.emacs`-file?

I am using emacs23 on Linux Mint 8.

I have now installed [*color-theme*](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) with

```
sudo apt-get install emacs-goodies-el
```

But I don't get *Zenburn* when I start emacs, and there is no *Zenburn* when I do `M-x color-theme-<TAB> <RETURN>` in emacs.

This is my *.emacs*

```
(tool-bar-mode -1)

(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/sanoj/zenburn.el")
(require 'color-theme)
(load 'zenburn)  ;; requires that zenburn.el is in your load path
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-zenburn)))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to load color-theme and initialize with something like this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/color-theme.el/file")
(require 'color-theme)
(load 'zenburn)  ;; requires that zenburn.el is in your load path
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-zenburn)))
```

If your distribution of emacs doesn't already have color-theme installed, you'll need to download it first from http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/

Comment: Did you change `/path/to/color-theme.el/file`? Did you load zenburn.el? I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: zendburn.el (with a "d") or zenburn.el (without the "d")? I keep my own local el files in an elisp subdirectory under my home directory. I then have a line like the first one in my example to add `/home/dharris/elisp` to load-path.

Comment: Sorry I meant `zenburn.el`, and I have listed my `.emacs` in my question now.

Comment: Do I have to load it with any command or should the colors just be there when I start emacs?

Comment: I'm not sure how much more I can help with this since I can't see everything in your set up. Take a look for interesting error messages in the *Messages* buffer. You might also find some useful stuff on the color theme page on the emacs wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme

Comment: Thanks anyway! I think there is a bug in my elisp, because when I try to save a custom option emacs says: "Cannot save customixations; init file was not fully loaded". See my comment to: http://superuser.com/questions/127420/how-can-i-hide-the-tool-bar-in-emacs-persistently/127901#127901

Answer (score 1):

I'm an emacs newbie; but with emacs 23.2.1 on Vista, I got this by adding the following lines. I also had to name the file as *~/.emacs.d/zenburn-theme.el*.

```
(require 'color-theme)
(load-theme 'zenburn)
(color-theme-zenburn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of your code is boilerplate code from color-theme installation guide so should work fine. Look at the things that are different.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/sanoj/")
(require 'color-theme)
(require 'zenburn)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-initialize)
     (color-theme-zenburn)))
```

Your add-to-list must take a *DIRECTORY* name as an argument, that's your first mistake. Also, you mustn't *load*  zenburn, you must *require* it.

I just checked it on my emacs 23 on Arch and it works!

Answer (score 0):

thanks, doug. i'm running emacs 23 (emacs-snapshot-gtk and emacs-goodies-el .deb packages installed) on ubuntu 10.4. i found if i put the zenburn.el into my .emacs.d directory, i could omit the first line. also, i was getting errors from both the load and color-theme-initialize lines, so with these minor adjustments, your code works perfectly, and i have zenburn. YEAH!!!!! man. what a relief to the eyes. before this, i had been using X commandline parameters, or gnome keyboard shortcuts (windows_key + n) to reverse. but while these reversed the background, they were still too high contrast.  so thank you for the last piece in the puzzle!

```
(require 'color-theme)
(load "~/.emacs.d/zenburn")
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
  '(progn
     (color-theme-zenburn)))
```