# How do I install color schemes for Emacs?

Tags: linux, installation, emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I apply a color-scheme (.el file) in emacs?](https://superuser.com/questions/128828/how-can-i-apply-a-color-scheme-el-file-in-emacs)

I'm looking at the directions on [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme#toc1) site, but under the heading `Installing`, it asks me to move a couple of files to my `Load Path`. I'm not sure where these files are/where I'm supposed to get them from. Could someone point them out to me?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, that it wasn't obvious how to actually get color-theme on that site. It seems more of a wiki for add-ons to color-theme.

Nevertheless, I did some random surfing from the site you mentioned, and i combined that with a comparison of my own installation of color-themes for Emacs. This is my tip:

http://download.gna.org/color-theme/

Comment: And do we use the shell from within Emacs or does the Linux Shell work as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at this answer on Super User as well:
[How can I apply a color-scheme (.el file) in emacs?](https://superuser.com/questions/128828/how-can-i-apply-a-color-scheme-el-file-in-emacs).

Better yet, Emacs 24 will provide a new color theming facility as described on [color theming with emacs 24](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/12/color-theming-with-emacs-24.html) so I reckon you could simply switch to Emacs 24 today.